# pyhook with py2exe and PyQt4 create infinite number of dialog form when keyboard hit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, py2exe

I am creating key logger with python.

It works really good when I run script on PyCharm.

But when I compile them with py2exe, there are problem.

when keyboard hit, it creates other Qt dialog form.

Here is my sample code:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom
import time
import pyscreenshot as ps
import os
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4 import uic

class Form(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        log = open('log.txt', 'a')
        log.write('INIT!!!!\n')
        log.close()
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("Keyhook_gui.ui")
        self.ui.show()
        self.isrun = True
        self.pressed_set = {}
        self.picture_set = {}
        self.ui.start_button.clicked.connect(self.KeyLogStart)
        self.ui.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.KeyLogStop)

    def KeyLogStart(self):
        hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
        hooks_manager.KeyDown = self.KeyDownEvent
        hooks_manager.KeyUp = self.KeyUpEvent
        hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
        while self.run():
            pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()

    def KeyLogStop(self):
        log = open('log.txt', 'a')
        log.write('KeyLogStop\n')
        log.close()
        self.isrun = False

    def run(self):
        return self.isrun

    def KeyDownEvent(self, event):
        log = open('log.txt', 'a')
        log.write('KeyDownEvent in\n')
        log.close()
        try:
            if event.Key in self.pressed_set:
                log = open('log.txt', 'a')
                log.write('PASS IN\n')
                log.write(' event.Key = ' + str(event.Key) + '\n')
                log.write('pressed_set = ' + str(self.pressed_set) + '\n')
                log.close()
                pass
            else:
                self.pressed_set[event.Key] = time.time()
                self.picture_set[event.Key] = ps.grab()
                log = open('log.txt', 'a')
                log.write(str(event.Key) + ' Down\n')
                log.close()
        except Exception as e:
            log = open('log.txt', 'a')
            log.write(str(e) + 'a\n')
            log.close()

        log = open('log.txt', 'a')
        log.write('pressed_set = ' + str(self.pressed_set)+'\n')
        log.close()

        return True

    def KeyUpEvent(self, event):
        log = open('log.txt', 'a')
        log.write(str(event.Key) + ' Up\n')
        log.write('pressed_set = ' + str(self.pressed_set) + '\n')
        log.close()
        pressed_time = time.time() - self.pressed_set.pop(event.Key)
        self.picture_set[event.Key].save('img/' + event.Key + '_' + str(pressed_time) + '.jpg')
        self.picture_set.pop(event.Key)

        return True

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Form()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.isdir('./img'):
        os.mkdir('./img')

    main()
```

here is log file:

```
INIT!!!!
KeyDownEvent in
INIT!!!!
```

when keyboard hit, it goes to def__init__.
and creates other Qt dialog.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: `while self.run(): pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()`  in `KeyLogStart` is probably a bad idea since an event handler should not perform any time consuming tasks.

Comment: @glls im using python 2.7.11

Comment: @J.J.Hakala then what whould be better solution?